# Matching images with regex in ubot

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match only images with same resolution using regex in ubot studio.

Sample image urls that I want to match:

```
http://sample.com/Image/e7b89db921da411bae9eea3c1333f287/201605/word/word/640/480/imagename.jpeg
http://sample.com/Image/a3c133e411bae9ee3f287b89db921da7/201504/word/word/640/480/imagename2.jpeg
http://sample.com/Image/41187b89db921dbae9ee3f2a3c133ea7/201505/word2/word/640/480/imagename3.jpeg
```

but to don't match images like:
http://sample.com/Image/fdsfsdf.jpeg or other images.
I've started with `^(http.+)\.jpeg$` but this is matching all images.
I need something like this:

```
http://sample.com/Image/*/*/word/word/640/480/*.jpeg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your url contains `word2`, so your regex does not match.

Try this one `http:\/\/sample.com\/Image\/.*?\/.*?\/word2?\/word\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/.*?\.jpeg`

[Sample](https://regex101.com/r/a4mC0f/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use:

```
.*\/word\/640\/480\/.*
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. Simply stating a possible solution is not enough. You have to explain WHY that solution is correct. The purpose is to educate future readers. Please take a look at stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer